# Test case to match the length of options in a drop down

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

```
<select-list [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" (click)="onClick()">
  <option-item *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{option.label}}</option-item>
</select-list>

options: any[] = [
    {
      label: 'Card',
      value: 'Card'
    },
    {
      label: 'Account',
      value: 'Account'
    },
    {
      label: 'Test3',
      value: 'Test3'
    },
    {
      label: 'Test4',
      value: 'Test4'
    }
  ];
```

I'm trying to write a test case where it is checking if the amount of items in the dropdown are equivalent to the amount of items in the test data, here what I triedso far

```
it('TC 10: should create edl dropdown options', async(() => {
dropdown = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('select-list'));      expect(dropdown[].nativeElement.length).toEqual(component.paymentOptions.length);
    }));
```

Comment: can't you directly do a query on you option-item? By.css('option-item')

Comment: I tried that getting this error Expected 0 to equal... @YoannAugen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
it('TC 10: should create edl dropdown options', async(() => {
  component.paymentOptions = options;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const dropdownItems = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('option-item'));
  expect(dropdownItems.length).toEqual(component.paymentOptions.length);
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try querying for option-item directly, and then checking the length of that array, rather than trying to access fields underneath `dropdown`:

```
it('TC 10: should create edl dropdown options', async(() => {
    let optionItems = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('option-item')); 
    expect(optionItems.length).toEqual(component.paymentOptions.length);
}));
```